# Site broken after deleting inactive themes

Tags: themes

Serious problem here. I get this error on all pages including wp-admin, seemed to happen just after I deleted inactive themes.

`Notice: Undefined index: viewall in /home/sites/arch4.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/themes/arch4/functions-woocommerce.php on line 25 Warning: require(/home/sites/arch4.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/themes/storefront/inc/init.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/sites/arch4.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/themes/storefront/functions.php on line 11 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/sites/arch4.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/themes/storefront/inc/init.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear53:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/ZendFramework') in /home/sites/arch4.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/themes/storefront/functions.php on line 11`

I uploaded the deleted themes again from my backup, and even uploaded the entire wordpress install from my backup. I also tried deactivating all plugins via phpmyadmin.

Thanks in advance

---

**UPDATE** - I reset to the default theme via phpmyadmin so now I can access wp-admin but whenever I try to change the theme to anything else, the same error comes up for those themes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP is trying to load the `arch4` theme. which I believe to be a child theme of `storefront` but it doesn't find the required `init.php` file because my guess is that you didn't install storefront.

Try to install storefront by going to **appearance->Themes->Add New** and *then* try reactivating your theme

Comment: Or through WP-CLI with `wp theme install storefront` - http://wp-cli.org/commands/theme/install/

Comment: Thanks! I updated the `storefront` theme and I'm back up and running. Didn't realise `arch4` was a child theme.

Comment: Great, glad I could help!